# print a newline using tail call optimization

Tags: assembly, nasm, tail-call-optimization

There's this unanswered question in the Igor Zhirkov's book [Low-Level Programming](https://github.com/Apress/low-level-programming) :

"Try to rewrite print_newline without calling print_char or copying its code. Hint: read
about tail call optimization.".

I've spent some times reading about tail call optimization, but I can't figure out what would be the proper way of doing it.

Original code (without tail-call):  print_newline => print_char => print_string=>string_length=>print_string

```
string_length:
    xor rax, rax
.loop:
    cmp byte [rdi+rax], 0   ; if rdi =  0 (not an address), then seg fault
    je .end 
    inc rax
    jmp .loop 
.end:
    ret
print_string:
    push rdi
    call string_length
    pop rsi
    mov rdx, rax
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    syscall
    ret
print_char:
    push rdi
    mov rdi, rsp 
    call print_string 
    pop rdi
    ret
print_newline:
    mov rdi, 10
    jmp print_char
```

What could be a tail-call optimization of that ?

Comment: `print_newline` has tail call optimization applied to it.  Note how it is using `jmp` instead of `ret`.  So, the flow of control will be `print_newline`, `print_char`, `print_string`, back to `print_char`, back to `print_newline`'s caller (not back to `print_newline`).  Without tail call optimization, `print_newline` would read `mov rdi, 10; call print_char; ret`.

Comment: Thank Erik! So there's nothing to "rewrite", and the question makes no sense ?

Comment: (Note how it is using `jmp` instead of `call` + `ret`.)

Comment: Yes, TCO has already been applied to `print_newline` in the code you posted.

Comment: Great !   Very clear explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Not really an example of TCO, but you could also just put `print_newline: mov rdi, 10` on the line immediately before `print_char:`, so that `print_newline` will fall through into `print_char` without needing a jump at all.  Of course this trick only works once, e.g. you couldn't also do `print_space` this way.

Comment: @NateEldredge , but in this case, the functions are in a library.  So I can't add an orphan instruction before `print_char`.   Or maybe I don't understand. What do you mean by "fall through into `print_char`" ?

Comment: If you're looking to optimize *speed* (not code-size) of `print_newline`, don't let it waste time calling string_length.  Make another wrapper (or inline) `write` with a length so `print_newline`, `print_char`, and `print_uint` can use it.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of reference I will provide the solution in this thread too.

1. Without optimizations

```
print_newline:
    mov rdi, 10
    call print_char
    ret
print_char:
    push rdi
    mov rdi, rsp 
    call print_string 
    pop rdi
    ret
```

2. A tail call optimization. A sequence of instructions `call X` and `ret` can always be substituted by `jmp X`.

```
print_newline:
    mov rdi, 10
    jmp print_char
print_char:
    push rdi
    mov rdi, rsp 
    call print_string 
    pop rdi
    ret
```

3. Just falling into `print_char`; basically making a subroutine with two entry points.

```
print_newline:
    mov rdi, 10
print_char:
    push rdi
    mov rdi, rsp 
    call print_string 
    pop rdi
    ret
```

[Here is a more in-depth explanation in my blog](https://rubber-duck-typing.com/articles/2020/12/12/when-functions-dissolve/)

Comment: "A sequence of instructions `call X` and `ret` can always be substituted by `jmp X`." Not strictly true, if the X function uses eg `retn 2` to pop something off the stack.

Comment: You are right, when `ret` has an argument this is not applicable.

Comment: *For the sake of reference I will provide the solution in this thread too.* - if this is a duplicate of another Q&A, it's usually better to close one as a duplicate of the other. Or if the questions are different enough to justify similar but different answers, IMO it's good to link the other question (or your answer on it) which has something different to say about the same subject.  I guess these examples don't really belong in [printing a signed integer optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67393573), but your answer there could link here as well as your blog.